# what is type of ICMP packets? TCP or UDP

Tags: networking, ping, tcp, udp, icmp

The ping packet is a type of ICMP packet. Is there any relation between ICMP with TCP? In other words, can we guarantee their arrival in the network?
I want to know if ICMP packets in the network are TCP, UDP, both or none of them?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is there any relation between ICMP with TCP

Not directly.  ICMP is IP protocol 1, TCP is IP protocol 6.  Other common IP protocols are 17 (udp) and 47 (gre).

> In other can we guaranty their arrival in the network

Typically ICMP is not sent within any type of framework that uses acknowledgements and timeouts like TCP does.  So the answer here is no.

> I want to know ICMP packets in the network is tcp or udp or which one or non of them?

None of them.  It behaves mostly like udp but it's not designed to transport data.  There is no "link" or session created with ICMP, it's typically a very simple request-response, if that.  You could "hack" ICMP to trade data over echo ICMP packets if you really wanted to.

Comment: So if it doesn't use TCP, if an ICMP packet is lost, how would you know?

Comment: You simply assume after a timeout period that you will not get a response and that no one is on the other end.

Answer (score 11):

None of them – they're sent directly over IP. ICMP packets are mainly used for network control, i. e. between routers or ping and many other uses.

Comment: is there any guaranty for that? assume your ICMP packet last in the link

Comment: It doesn't matter as it's a totally different protocol and the most routers and firewalls handle it differently.In the Wikipedia article for ICMP you can read the following: ICMP differs from transport protocols such as TCP and UDP in that it is not typically used to exchange data between systems, nor is it regularly employed by end-user network applications (with the exception of some diagnostic tools like ping and traceroute) -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol

Comment: @alex: The ICMP protocol doesn't provide for guaranteed delivery. Given the kinds of tasks it performs that wouldn't be possible anyway (e.g sending an ICMP echo request to the IP-address of a server that is down)